# Defining the partition for an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

So I am currently learning about relations and functions in a more formal way than what I am used to. Therefore I decided to tackle some beginning problems, but I have stumbled upon this problem, where I am not quite sure how to solve it:

For a relation $$a \mathcal R b \Leftrightarrow 3|(a^2 - b^2)$$ where $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers, show that this relation is an equivalence relation and determine its partition.

It was quite easy to show that it is indeed an equivalence relation and I also know that the partition of equivalence relations is the set of all their equivalence classes. However, I am not quite sure whether that really answers the problem. So I tried giving a more formal answer like this:

For a given element b of the set of whole numbers the equivalence class contains all integer values of $a = \pm \sqrt{b^2 + 3k}$ where $k$ is just an integer. This comes from $$3|(a^2 - b^2) \Rightarrow a^2 = b^2 + 3k.$$ And the set of all these sets is then the partition. Would this be "determining" the partition or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This equivalence relation has very few equivalence classes, and you can explicitly list them quite easily. I suggest looking at, say, the numbers from 1 to 10 and classifying them into equivalence classes. You'll probably notice a simple pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just don't know how I couldn't see something that obvious. If I pick a to be multiple of 3 then b must also be one so that their difference can be a multiple of 3. And if I pick a not to be a multiple of 3 it is either a = 3m + 1 or a = 3n + 2. Either way it then works out that b must then also be either b = 3n + 2 or b = 3m + 1.